# Ways to save a lot of text and images in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, data-storage

**Short version at the bottom**

I'm working on an android app for a computer game, Heroes Of Newerth. A part of the apps functionality is to list all the heroes in the game. Each hero has:

- a short description
- a few stats(faction and primary attribute)
- an icon
- 4 spells, which also has:

  - a short description
  - a few stats (mana cost, difference in ranks, etc.)
  - an icon.

There are approximately 110 heroes, which means I have about 500 sets of descriptions and stats.

I made a working version of the app. I downloaded all the images and put them in the `drawable` folder *(note, this was 500 images)*, and created a `Hero Enum` which stored `name`, `faction` and `primary attribute`. Obviously, this was a bad idea, as it was horrible looking, and hard to extend to storing the rest of the data.

I have though about using a database, but as I don't have any experience with databases, I'm not really sure as how to do this, especially in Android. I looked it up, and it seems I need to initialize the database on the phone, which means I have to get that data from somewhere - which, again, means I'm back to square one.

I have never worked with this much data in a programming project, and have no idea for how to save it all. As if this is not enough, the game developer, S2 Games, releases new heroes with only weeks in between. As I wouldn't want to update one of my apps every other week, I want the app to be able to update itself with the new data. The best way I see this in my head is you download the app, either with a database of the current heroes, or without any, and the app checks each friday(patches are released on fridays) if the app is up to date. If not, update the database(with text and icons).

## Short version

I want to save a few thousand strings, some formated in a special way(unless I can to this afterwards), and about 500 icons. How should I approach this?

*Note: I know this was a really bad question, with a horrible structure, but I've been stuck here for weeks, and I couldn't get myself to ask someone, I really need help here!*

Answer (score 0):

well it's very recommended that you use sql and databases . you could go to w3schools for the basics .

if you don't want to use DB (or don't have time) , you can store all the data in xml files , and then parse them all . the images should never be part of the DB (or the xml files) , since they cause a bad performance while moving between items.put their names/paths instead .

if the images take a lot of space , consider using google expansion library .